# markitup changes the explicitly set size of textarea?

Tags: jquery, markitup

I set up several textarea's with diffrent sizes as:

```
<textarea class="markItUp" rows="5" cols="80" name="upstring">
```

or

```
<textarea class="markItUp" rows="100" cols="80" name="upstring">
```

But after the markitup has been applied they are always resized to 18 rows. Why?

I have checked rows with firebug and its unchanged (still 5 or 100) so changing that wont help.

Since I have lots of texts I want to do small edits to I do not what to have a to small or to big area to start with since I already know the appropriate size.

Pleas help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some playing around to understand things I produced the following code to solve my problem:

```
jQuery(".markItUp").markItUp(mySettings).css('height', function() {
  /* Since line-height is set in the markItUp-css, fetch that value and
  split it into value and unit.  */
  var h = jQuery(this).css('line-height').match(/(\d+)(.*)/)
  /* Multiply line-height-value with nr-of-rows and add the unit.  */
  return (h[1]*jQuery(this).attr('rows'))+h[2]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS rules generally override the rows and cols attributes, so rather than rely on those, try sizing your textareas with css 'height' and 'width.'